# SVG javascript chart scraping

Tags: charts, highcharts, web-crawler, screen-scraping, yahoo-finance

When i access a yahoo finance for intraday data they show a interactive chart, but i only can find the data for the row my mouse was over the last time it was in the chart, it automatically updates the html... and then if go to the << left on the chart, the server request more data for the hide part from the chart...

example:
http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=JPM

so my question is, in what file i can find all this data? i mean, they don't send it everytime my mouse go over the chart, so it must be stored somewhere...
the values of open,close,low,high,volume,%chg

or more right to the point,
how do i scrape data from this kind of charts?, i mean i give the url to one crawler and then it download all the from this chart, including move the chart to the << left until they stop to send more data

any ideias?

edit:

i heard about this selenium+python
anyone have any ideias? i still stuck =//

Answer (score 1):

1) this chart is produced by javascript. Try to disable javascript and refresh page -> no chart
2) the chart is SVG
3) to be able to download SVG, you need a javascript capable library, like [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/)
4) you have to fetch what's in tag `svg viewBox`

Maybe a good start is beginning by something easy, like the tiger: http://raphaeljs.com/tiger.html

Comment: thanks it already give me something to search, but i couldn't find a way to do this, i will try search questions about phantomjs and scraping svg, thanks for the help =)

Comment: The way to thanks on SO is to upvote/accept answers ;)

Comment: i tried but i can't upvote >_< i need more rep, i will accept it later if no one answer anything better

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can get stock data from NASDAQ in Excel spreadsheet format to work with. http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/jpm/historical

They also allow you to set the time period of data you would like to access, as well.

Comment: actually i want intraday data, the problem is i can even get from this link, but i would have to make a http request every minute to do so, and it's a big waste if i can fetch with one request on the chart a whole day, it would take like more than 4000 requests for each stock action vs 1 request scraping out the chart, for daily open/close it's fine this way, for intraday(each minute/5 by 5 mim no),  >_< i really want to get the whole data from the svg chart, just don't know how